# Flutter IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName is returning null after registration of the port

Tags: flutter

I am trying to register a port of stream event listeners in flutter and facing an error that after registration of the port I am unable to lookup the same port as it is returning null every time I am looking for it .

```
if (IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("_notficationListener_") == null) {
      print('going to fresh port');
      IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
          receivePort.sendPort, "_notificationListener_");
      NotificationsListener.initialize(callbackHandle: _callback);
      receivePort.listen((var message) => {
            print(
                "Checking whether it is passing or not ======================"),
            onData(message)
          });

      bool? isRunning = await NotificationsListener.isRunning;

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("""Service is ${isRunning == false ? "not" : ""} running""");
      }

      started = isRunning!;
    } else {
      IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping("_notficationListener_");
      IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
          receivePort.sendPort, "_notificationListener_");
      NotificationsListener.initialize(callbackHandle: _callback);
      receivePort.listen((var message) => {
            print(
                "Checking whether it is passing or not ======================"),
            onData(message)
          });

      bool? isRunning = await NotificationsListener.isRunning;

      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("""Service is ${isRunning == false ? "not" : ""} running""");
      }

      started = isRunning!;
    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(
          "port is present ${IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("_notficationListener_")}");
    }
```

Here is the code I am working on . Any help will be appreciated . package user Flutter Isolate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
receivePort.sendPort, "*notificationListener*"); is having some error with the trailing __ and __ before the name , i removed that and it worked .